# I couldn't play a video with the <video> tag

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, html5-video

I have a problem with the video tag. After few hours of search I've seen a lot of solutions which do not solve my problem. So I come to you.

Here is my code:

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="test.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="test.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.
</video>
```

And Firefox says to me:

> no video with supported format and mime type found.

I have an **.htaccess** in the folder where my **.php** is where there are:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Thanks in advance.